# Create string.out from string.in in C

Tags: c, string

I want to read in from the arguments a file with a name of format **filename.in** and output a file with the exact same **filename** but with **.out** extension instead of **.in** (**filename.out**). The key is that **filename** can be anything.

This code compiles correctly and does the job I want, but when I run it with valgrind I get a bunch of errors. Can anyone tell me what's causing the errors?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i, dotIndex;
    char extOut[] = ".out";
    char *filenameIn, *filenameOut, *aux;
    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;

    filenameIn = argv[1];

    aux = strchr(filenameIn, '.');
    dotIndex = aux - filenameIn;

    aux = (char *)malloc((strlen(filenameIn) - 1)*sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0; i < dotIndex; i++)
      aux[i] = filenameIn[i];

    filenameOut = (char *)malloc((strlen(aux) + 5)*sizeof(char));

    strcat(aux, extOut);
    strcpy(filenameOut, aux);

     /* open input file */
     fpIn  = fopen(filenameIn,"r");
     if(fpIn == NULL) {
       printf("Open error of input file\n");
    exit(2);
     }

     /* open output file */
     fpOut = fopen(filenameOut,"w");
     if(fpOut == NULL) {
       printf("Open error of output file\n");
   exit(3);
     }

     fclose(fpOut);
     fclose(fpIn);
     free(aux);
     free(filenameOut);

     exit(0);
     }

The valgrind report:

 Command: ./doorsmaze text.in
==3493== 
==3493== Invalid write of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C36B: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487AB: main (main.c:64)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef02e is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== Invalid write of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C390: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487AB: main (main.c:64)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef030 is 2 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== Invalid read of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C6C5: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487BF: main (main.c:65)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef02e is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== 
==3493== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3493==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3493==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 719 bytes allocated
==3493== 
==3493== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3493==  Command: ./doorsmaze text.in
==3493== 
==3493== Invalid write of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C36B: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487AB: main (main.c:64)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef02e is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== Invalid write of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C390: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487AB: main (main.c:64)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef030 is 2 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== Invalid read of size 1
==3493==    at 0x402C6C5: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x80487BF: main (main.c:65)

==3493==  Address 0x41ef02e is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==3493==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x8048716: main (main.c:55)

==3493== 
==3493== 
==3493== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3493==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3493==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 719 bytes allocated


==3493== 
==3493== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

==3493== 
==3493== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==3493== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


==3493== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==3493== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: @John3136 I can't copy the errors from the terminal but they are "Invalid write of size 1 at strcat"

Comment: wrong `dotIndex = aux - filenameOut;` (filenameOut --> filenameIn) filenameOut not set.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I just copied it wrong; what I have in my code is what you mean. Editted the post.

Comment: It is used before the content is also set in the other ex) `strlen(filenameOut)`

Comment: ?? Can't copy the errors?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that was another typo. it's completely fine now. (except for the main question)

Comment: haha, typo too much. `filenameIn = (char *)malloc((strlen(aux) + 5)*sizeof(char));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm so sorry... stupid me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your code

- You might not get the last `.` in the filename

  ```
  aux = strchr(filenameIn, '.');
  ```

  better use [`strrchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr). You should also check for `NULL`, just in case the filename doesn't include an extension.
- You allocate memory large enough to hold `filename.in` (excluding the nul byte)

  ```
  aux = (char *)malloc((strlen(filenameIn) - 1)*sizeof(char));
  ```
- You do your own version of [`strncpy(aux, filenameIn, dotIndex)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

  ```
  for(i = 0; i < dotIndex; i++)
      aux[i] = filenameIn[i];`
  ```
- You write beyond the allocated buffer, because you miss the space for the last character plus the nul byte

  ```
  strcat(aux, extOut);
  ```

  To fix this, you must allocate enough memory, which is the length of `filename.in` plus 1 char ("out" is one longer than "in") plus nul byte

  ```
  aux = (char *)malloc((strlen(filenameIn) + 2)*sizeof(char));
  ```

Comment: A *potential* issue is `strchr(filenameIn, '.')`. The OP must be working on Windows or DOS 'cause that won't fly on my Mac. Anyway, I'd use `strrchr` instead, starting from the last -- if any -- path separator.

Comment: I'm sorry but those last two bullets refer to old code that I had copied wrong to the post

Comment: @Jongware, user2449629 Thank you, both issues fixed.